# awk to pass a bash variable to script to insert value on each line

Tags: awk

Trying to pass a `bash` variable to an `awk` script to insert a value in front of each line, currently the script runs but prints `0` in each line. Thank you :).

**file**

```
2022/.../.../...
2022/.../.../...
```

**awk**

```
id=1234

awk -v r="$id" '{print /"id"/"/"$0}'
```

**current**

```
0/2022/.../.../...
0/2022/.../.../...
```

**desired**

```
1234/2022/.../.../...
1234/2022/.../.../...
```

Comment: Use: `awk -v r="$id" '{print r "/" $0}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing variable correctly but not using correctly inside the `awk`.
`/"id"/"` is a regex expression that will attempt to match `"id"` string in each line and since it doesn't exist it returns `0` and that's what you get in output.

You may just use:

```bash
awk -v r="$id" '{print r "/" $0}' file

1234/2022/.../.../...
1234/2022/.../.../...
```

btw this sed solution would also work:

```bash
sed "s~^~$id/~" file

1234/2022/.../.../...
1234/2022/.../.../...
```

Answer (score 1):

this should make it clear why it appended `"0/"` :

```
0/
    # gawk profile, created Tue Aug 30 14:49:38 2022

    # Rule(s)

     1  {
     1      print (/"id"/) "/" $0
    }
```

It's a `regex` non-match, concat with a string containing ASCII `"/"` (`\057` | `0x2F`)`, then concat with input row